# Calculating magnification of a put together telescope

Tags: optics, telescopes, optical-materials

My objective lens has focal length of 50 cm and I am using a 10x eyepiece (I don't have anymore info). I am not sure how to calcuate the focal length of eyepiece. How do I find the total magnification as well?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that your eyepiece doesn't have the focal length printed on the barrel (also are you sure it's a telescope eyepiece and not microscope?).   What brand is your eyepiece? That may help you determine the total barrel distance the manufacturer assumes  is between the objective's primary focus and the eyepiece.

Comment: That said,  hold your eyepiece in a uniform light source like the sun and adjust until the spot image is as small as you can get.  Now you know its focal length.   Calculating the total telescope magnification given the two lens's focal lengths is trivial -- see the Wikipedia pages.